# Photoshop CS6: Brush strokes looking completely different on desktop compared to laptop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

So on my laptop, here is what the brush looks like, along with its properties. The lines are more clear than the ones in the next image:

[image]

Now on my desktop, the brush is the same and so are the properties. It’s just that it looks more pixelated and the glow around the brush width is bigger even with identical brush properties

[image]

What is the reason for this? And it’s not just when I edit it in Photoshop, when I save the image as a PNG file, the results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same.

Simple mistake; your first example is at 100% zoom, your second is at 300% zoom (the pixelation should have given that away).

Just to show you, here are both of your images at the same zoom:

[image]

Not sure why they would look any different when exported as a PNG. At a guess one image is actually 3 times larger in pixel dimensions and you're viewing them at the same size on screen.

Comment: Hmm..this is weird, because when I apply 300% zoom on my laptop (the first picture),  the zoom passes the borders of the picture. But when I do a 300% zoom on my desktop (2nd picture), it still shows the borders and the full image. But you are right, both images are the same.

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of each document? I assume that's what's going on but it's hard to know for sure (the PS UI looks roughly the same size so it doesn't look like a screen resolution issue, not sure though)

Comment: how would I find out the pixel dimensions?

Comment: Image -> Image Size